# Handling two urls fetching

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to use React to handle two separate url fetches.

```
  try {
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${apiToken}&language=en-UsS&query=${searchInput}&page=1&include_adult=false`
  );

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error('something went wrong!');
  }

  const { results } = await response.json();
  console.log (results);
  const bookData = results.map((book) => ({
    bookId: book.id,
    title: book.title,
    description: book.overview,
  }));
```

The problem that I'm running into is that this particular api needs a separate fetch for images. Can someone show me how to properly handle this?

Comment: What stops you to send another API request using `fetch`?

Comment: Nothing. I just couldn't find if there was a cleaner way to handle multiple fetches